# Get Product ordered by percent_off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two model Product and PricingHistory.

Product(id, name) has_many PricingHistory (id, percent_off, product_id)

I need to join Product with lastest PricingHistory and order it by percent_off.

I wrote this:

```
Product.joins(:pricing_histories).group('products.id').order("max(pricing_histories.id) ASC").order('max(pricing_histories.percent_off) DESC')
```

But its not returning the data in order.

Eg:
Product:

```
ID    PRODUCT 
1       aa
2       bb
3       cc
```

PricingHistory

```
PRODUCT_ID PERCENT_OFF   CREATED_ON
   1          10         10/10/2015
   1          20         10/11/2015
   2          30         10/12/2015
   2          40         10/13/2015
   3          50         10/14/2015
   3          60         10/14/2015
```

I want the result to be:

```
 ID    PRODUCT  PRODUCT_ID PERCENT_OFF CREATED_ON
 1       aa     1          20         10/11/2015
 2       bb     2          40         10/13/2015
 3       cc     3          60         10/14/2015
```

Comment: All products will have a unique id, so grouping by `products.id` won't do anything useful.  Maybe you mean `pricing_histories.product_id`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I tried that one too but still not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follows:

PricingHistory.joins(:product).group('products.id').order('pricing_histories.percent_off DESC')